# Filter geo_distance isn`t working with nested objects

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

**I'm using version 7.13.2 of elastic search and the new version of their lib**

I'm trying to make a geo_distance filter in **nodejs**, but the typing doesn't seem to be recognized, maybe it's because of the 'nested' type, because I tested the documentation example and it worked, follow the link:
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html)

the index is mapped like this:

(ps: I only left the fields that interest us)

```
mappings: {
 properties: {
   id: { type: "integer" },
   profile: {
     type: "nested",
     properties: {
       id: { type: "integer" },   
       address: { 
         type: "nested", 
         properties: {
           id: { type: "integer" },
           location: { type: "geo_point" },
         } 
       },
     },
   },
 }
}
```

the data I'm entering is these

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "profile": {
            "id": 2,
            "name: "Test"
            "address": [{
                "id": 1
                "location": "-20.771, -51.70"
             },
               "address": [{
                "id": 2
                "location": "-20.772, -51.72"
             }],
        }
}
```

the search I'm doing is like this:

```
let params: RequestParams.Search = {
      index: index,
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match_all: {},
              },
            ],
            should: [],
            filter: {
              geo_distance: {
                distance: "5mi",
                "profile.address.location": {
                  lat: "-20.78",
                  lon: "-51.70",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

the error that appears in the search is this:

> Field [profile.address.location] is of unsupported type [text] for
> [geo_distance] query

the same search I'm making works for the documentation example, but in my case it's giving the error mentioned above

Comment: In your mapping you have a top-level `npo` nested field, but it's neither present in your document nor in your query.

Comment: the insert is normally, I can search with other attributes @Val

Comment: What you insert into your index doesn't match the mapping, so that's why your query is not working. if you run `GET your-index/_mapping` you'll see it's not the same as the one you're defining at index creation time.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I tested it here by taking the `npo`, but the other parts of my query stop working

Comment: All I'm saying is that the data you're entering doesn't match your mapping. So either modify your mapping or your document. Then when both are in synch we can look at the query, otherwise we're comparing apples and oranges

Comment: I edited the mapping in the question for what I'm testing right now

Comment: Ok, now we're good. Answering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `location` is located inside a (doubly) `nested` field, your query needs to leverage the [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) as well:

```
let params: RequestParams.Search = {
      index: index,
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match_all: {},
              },
            ],
            should: [],
            filter: {
              nested: {
                path: "profile",
                query: {
                  nested: {
                    path: "profile.address",
                    query: {
                      geo_distance: {
                        distance: "5mi",
                        "profile.address.location": {
                          lat: "-20.78",
                          lon: "-51.70",
                        },
                      },
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

Comment: it worked, thank you very much, now I just need to fix the rest, but with your answer I can do it now